# Basic Rotation Based Encrypt/Decrypt Issues

Tags: ruby, encryption, rotation, irb

Basically I'm following Jumpstart's lab's challenge Encryptor program, and have run into some issues.

Here is my code

```
class Encryptor
  def cipher(rotation)
    characters = (' '..'z').to_a
    rotated_characters = characters.rotate(rotation)
    Hash[characters.zip(rotated_characters)]
  end

  def encrypt_letter(letter, rotation)
    cipher_for_rotation = cipher(rotation)
    cipher_for_rotation[letter]
  end

  def encrypt(string, rotation)
    letters = string.split("")

    results = letters.collect do |letter|
        encrypt_letter = encrypt_letter(letter, rotation)
    end

    results.join
  end

  def decrypt_letter(letter, rotation)
    cipher_for_rotation = cipher(rotation)
    reversed_cipher = cipher_for_rotation.to_a.reverse.to_h
    reversed_cipher[letter]
  end

  def decrypt(string, rotation)
    letters = string.split("")

    results = letters.collect do |letter|
        decrypt_letter = decrypt_letter(letter, rotation)
    end

    results.join
  end
end
```

I'm running into difficulties with my decrypt method. Here is the following pasted from irb

```
2.3.0 :001 > load './encryptor.rb'
 => true
2.3.0 :002 > e = Encryptor.new
 => #<Encryptor:0x007fe93a0319b8>
2.3.0 :003 > encrypted = e.encrypt("Hello, World!", 10)
 => "Rovvy6*ay!vn+"
2.3.0 :004 > e.decrypt(encrypted, 10)
 => "\\y%%(@4k(+%x5"
```

As you can see, when decrypting my encrypted string it should be outputting "Hello, World!", what I encrypted it with, with a rotation of 10. Don't see what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely an issue with my decrypt_letter function. Check out the following after some debugging in irb:

e.encrypt_letter('t',13)
 => "&"
> e.decrypt_letter('&',13)
 => "3"

Comment: Is there a better method than my '.to_a.reverse.to_h' method?

Comment: I admit I haven't looked deeply at your code, but the fact that your decrypt and encrypt methods look differently is a red flag for me. (Actually, the fact that you even have two methods at all is suspicious.) From what I can understand of your code, you are implementing a Caesar Cipher, and the Caesar Cipher is completely symmetrical: encrypting and decrypting are exactly the same thing, just with different keys. There shouldn't be two methods, and there *certainly* shouldn't be two *different* methods for encryption and decryption, since both are exactly the same.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you so much for the response, I'm just grasping the basics of ruby here. I'm following this tutorial: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/encryptor.html which I guess leads me through implementing the methods as you mentioned but shows the wrong way to do it first? Not sure. Will definitely heed your advice and do some more research.

Comment: Basically, `decrypt(10)` is the same as `encrypt(-10)`, which in turn is the same as `encrypt(17)` (assuming a 27 "letter" alphabet). More generally, `decrypt(N) == encrypt(-N) == encrypt(alphabet.size - N)`.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: `cipher_for_rotation.to_a.reverse.to_h`. You turn the dictionary into an array, reverse the array (i.e. reverse the order of the dictionary), and then turn it into a dictionary again. But order doesn't matter for dictionaries, so you end up with the same dictionary you started with. To be more precise: Ruby `Hash`es *do* preserve the insertion order of keys, and are guaranteed to iterate in that order, so what you have done is reverse the insertion order (and thus reverse the iteration order). But you never iterate over the hash, you only access its values.

Comment: So it's essentially a NO-OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could just look up the key of the hash.

```
def decrypt_letter(letter, rotation)
  cipher_for_rotation = cipher(rotation)
  cipher_for_rotation.key(letter)
end
```

Example:

```
irb(main):003:0> e = Encryptor.new
=> #<Encryptor:0x007fbcea9b65c8>
irb(main):004:0> enc = e.encrypt "Hello, World!", 10
=> "Rovvy6*ay!vn+"
irb(main):005:0> e.decrypt enc, 10
=> "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: This might be exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the input. Yes, this works perfectly. thanks a bunch